# How to add users and computers back to server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, domain-controller, user-management

I have windows 2012 server which I had to nuke due to virus issue, which has active directory setup with users and computers. Now I have installed fresh windows server and setup ad & dc with same name as it was and wanted to add all existing users and computers to it without affecting user files/folders on their machines.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The new AD has different UUIDs that are used internally. You will have to start from scratch, add all users, computers, recreate all permissions, ownerships etc.

It would have been better if you had set up a second domain controller, even if it is only temporary.

Comment: TBH, If you still have a backup of the old installation I'd restore it, set up a second DC and then reinstall that server again. It's still way, WAY less work than resetting all permissions of all files and folders on all machines.

Comment: but remind that it should not older as 30 days, since the computer keys are syncing usually in this period